# C# - Formatting Yelp API Output

Tags: c#, json, api, formatting, yelp

So I'm brand new to APIs in general. They're exciting because I can actually start making real programs. That said, I've figured out how to get results back from Yelp. The thing is, they come back formatted like this:

```
{
    "businesses": [
        {
            "categories": [
                [
                    "Local Flavor",
                    "localflavor"
                ],
                [
                    "Mass Media",
                    "massmedia"
                ]
            ],
            "display_phone": "+1-415-908-3801",
            "id": "yelp-san-francisco",
            "image_url": "http://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/nQK-6_vZMt5n88zsAS94ew/ms.jpg",
            "is_claimed": true,
            "is_closed": false,
            "location": {
                "address": [
                    "140 New Montgomery St"
                ],
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "coordinate": {
                    "latitude": 37.7867703362929,
                    "longitude": -122.399958372115
                },
                "country_code": "US",
                "cross_streets": "Natoma St & Minna St",
                "display_address": [
                    "140 New Montgomery St",
                    "Financial District",
                    "San Francisco, CA 94105"
                ],
                "geo_accuracy": 9.5,
                "neighborhoods": [
                    "Financial District",
                    "SoMa"
                ],
                "postal_code": "94105",
                "state_code": "CA"
            },
            "mobile_url": "http://m.yelp.com/biz/yelp-san-francisco",
            "name": "Yelp",
            "phone": "4159083801",
            "rating": 2.5,
            "rating_img_url": "http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7fb9aff59f9/ico/stars/v1/stars_2_half.png",
            "rating_img_url_large": "http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/d63e3add9901/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_2_half.png",
            "rating_img_url_small": "http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/8e8633e5f8f0/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_2_half.png",
            "review_count": 7140,
            "snippet_image_url": "http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/YcjPScwVxF05kj6zt10Fxw/ms.jpg",
            "snippet_text": "What would I do without Yelp?\n\nI wouldn't be HALF the foodie I've become it weren't for this business.    \n\nYelp makes it virtually effortless to discover new...",
            "url": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/yelp-san-francisco"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2316
}
```

I don't understand how I would separate this data out and insert proper formatting into it to display it normally on a WinForm or web page. There does not seem to be a way for me to access each piece of data. I typed "response." in the IDE in reference to the JObject, but for example, there is no bool type called response.is_closed... Here is the code for my simple program below. Obviously I'm wanting to convert this to a web app or WinForm but I'd even explore formatting it nicely in the command line window,because this data displayed this way is ugly. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using CommandLine;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using SimpleOAuth;

/// <summary>
/// Yelp API v2.0 code sample.
/// This program demonstrates the capability of the Yelp API version 2.0
/// by using the Search API to query for businesses by a search term and location,
/// and the Business API to query additional information about the top result
/// from the search query.
///
/// Please refer to http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation for the API documentation.
///
/// Sample usage of the program:
/// `YelpAPI.exe --term="bars" --location="San Francisco, CA"`
/// </summary>
namespace YelpAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class that encapsulates the logic for querying the API.
    ///
    /// Users have to set the OAuth credentials properties
    /// in order to use this class.
    /// </summary>
    class YelpAPIClient
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Consumer key used for OAuth authentication.
        /// This must be set by the user.
        /// </summary>
        private const string CONSUMER_KEY = "CENSORED";

        /// <summary>
        /// Consumer secret used for OAuth authentication.
        /// This must be set by the user.
        /// </summary>
        private const string CONSUMER_SECRET = "CENSORED";

        /// <summary>
        /// Token used for OAuth authentication.
        /// This must be set by the user.
        /// </summary>
        private const string TOKEN = "CENSORED";

        /// <summary>
        /// Token secret used for OAuth authentication.
        /// This must be set by the user.
        /// </summary>
        private const string TOKEN_SECRET = "CENSORED";

        /// <summary>
        /// Host of the API.
        /// </summary>
        private const string API_HOST = "https://api.yelp.com";

        /// <summary>
        /// Relative path for the Search API.
        /// </summary>
        private const string SEARCH_PATH = "/v2/search/";

        /// <summary>
        /// Relative path for the Business API.
        /// </summary>
        private const string BUSINESS_PATH = "/v2/business/";

        /// <summary>
        /// Search limit that dictates the number of businesses returned.
        /// </summary>
        private const int SEARCH_LIMIT = 3;

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepares OAuth authentication and sends the request to the API.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseURL">The base URL of the API.</param>
        /// <param name="queryParams">The set of query parameters.</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON response from the API.</returns>
        /// <exception>Throws WebException if there is an error from the HTTP request.</exception>
        private JObject PerformRequest(string baseURL, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams=null)
        {
            var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);

            if (queryParams == null)
            {
                queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            foreach (var queryParam in queryParams)
            {
                query[queryParam.Key] = queryParam.Value;
            }

            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseURL);
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

            var request = WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.ToString());
            request.Method = "GET";

            request.SignRequest(
                new Tokens {
                    ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY,
                    ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    AccessToken = TOKEN,
                    AccessTokenSecret = TOKEN_SECRET
                }
            ).WithEncryption(EncryptionMethod.HMACSHA1).InHeader();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            return JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Query the Search API by a search term and location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="term">The search term passed to the API.</param>
        /// <param name="location">The search location passed to the API.</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON response from the API.</returns>
        public JObject Search(string term, string location)
        {
            string baseURL = API_HOST + SEARCH_PATH;
            var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "term", term },
                { "location", location },
                { "limit", SEARCH_LIMIT.ToString() }
            };
            return PerformRequest(baseURL, queryParams);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Query the Business API by a business ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="business_id">The ID of the business to query.</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON response from the API.</returns>
        public JObject GetBusiness(string business_id)
        {
            string baseURL = API_HOST + BUSINESS_PATH + business_id;
            return PerformRequest(baseURL);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Command-line options abstraction.
    /// </summary>
    class Options
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets and sets the Term property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The search term specified by the user.</value>
        [Option('t', "term", DefaultValue="dinner", HelpText = "Search term")]
        public string Term { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets and sets the Location property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The location term specified by the user.</value>
        [Option('l', "location", DefaultValue="San Francisco, CA", HelpText = "Search Location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that encapsulates the program entry point.
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Queries the API by the input values from the user, and prints
        /// the result on the console.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="term">The search term to query.</param>
        /// <param name="location">The location of the business to query.</param>
        public static void QueryAPIAndPrintResult(string term, string location)
        {
            var client = new YelpAPIClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Querying for {0} in {1}...", term, location);

            JObject response = client.Search(term, location);

            JArray businesses = (JArray)response.GetValue("businesses");

            if (businesses.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No businesses for {0} in {1} found.", term, location);
                return;
            }

            string business_id = (string)businesses[0]["id"];

            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} businesses found, querying business info for the top result \"{1}\"...",
                businesses.Count,
                business_id
            );

            response = client.GetBusiness(business_id);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result for business {0} found:", business_id));        
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Program entry point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command-line arguments.</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool exit = false;
            do
            {
                var options = new Options();
                string locationInput = "";
                string businessTypeInput = "";
                try
                {
                    CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options);
                }
                catch (CommandLine.ParserException)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to parse command line options.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                }

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the location: ");
                    locationInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the type of business:");
                    businessTypeInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    Program.QueryAPIAndPrintResult(businessTypeInput, locationInput);
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to search again? Y/N?");
                    if (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "N")
                        exit = true;
                    else
                        exit = false;
                }
                catch (WebException error)
                {
                    if (error.Response != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(error.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            Console.Error.WriteLine("Response returned: {0}", reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }

                    Console.Error.WriteLine("HTTP request failed, got {0}, abort program.", error.Message);
                }
            } while (exit == false);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Documentation is here: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

Which lists out all of the data I am supposed to be able to grab.

If you want to run this, you'll need the Oauth info which you can get here: https://www.yelp.com/developers/manage_api_keys

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while looking for some information on the Yelp API, so I just did this myself. In case you haven't found an answer yet, there are a few ways you can go about parsing a json object. In both of the following examples, you would need to pull out just the businesses and then loop over the listings within businesses.

```
//yelpJsonReturned is whatever you named your Json object returned by the API.
//"businesses" indicates that you only want the parts of that object listed under businesses
var businesses = yelpJsonReturned["businesses"]

foreach (JsonValue business in businesses)
{
     //parsing code goes here
}
```

1)

```
//parsing code goes here
var businessList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YelpListing>>(yourJsonString)
```

This will take each listing and map it onto a YelpListing model that you've created. Unfortunately, I had no luck with this because the YelpListing model has to exactly match what is being returned by the GET request, and I kept getting type conversion errors because the API's return string is a bit convoluted in spots. Also, it had a lot of information that I didn't really need to use.

2) You can also use the same idea as the `yelpJsonReturned["businesses"]` to pull out individual parts of the business string. Given the nesting in this Json object, I found it easiest to pull out the objects individually and then map them all into a flat model that I can use elsewhere in my program. It might not be the most efficient way to go about it, but I liked the control I had over my subsequent model and it certainly saved me some frustration in mapping to the YelpListing object. Here's what I used.

```
var yelpListingList = new List<YelpListing>();

var businesses = yelpJsonReturned["businesses"];

foreach (JsonValue business in businesses)
{
    //parsing code goes here

    var location = business["location"];
    var address = location["address"];
    var coordinates = location["coordinate"];

    var listing = new YelpListing()
    {
        Id = business["id"],
        Name = business["name"],
        Address = address[0],
        City = location["city"],
        Latitude = coordinates["latitude"],
        Longitude = coordinates["longitude"],
        LocationClosed = business["is_closed"],
        MobileUrl = business["mobile_url"],
        Rating = business["rating"],
        NumberReviews = business["review_count"],
        RatingImage = business["rating_img_url_small"]
    };

    yelpListingList.Add(listing);
}
```